# Extraction of string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, javascript-objects

I have a string of the following format:

```
"hello(%npm%)hi"
```

My goal is to split the string into three parts

```
a) hello
b) (%npm%)
c) hi
```

I am using regex as follows:

```
var myString = "hello(%npm%)hi".match(/[a-z]*/);
        var backdtring  = "hello(%npm%)hi".match(/\)[a-z]*/);
        var midstring  = "hello(%npm%)hi".match(/\(\%[a-z]*\%\)/);

var res = backdtring.replace(")", "");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1988/ff6aupmL/

I am trying in jsfiddle , where theres an error in the line:

```
var res = backdtring.replace(")", "");
```

**"backdtring.replace is not a function"** .

Whats wrong in the replace function above?

Update:
Also, have I used the best practices of regular expressions ?

Comment: `.match` of regex returns an array of matches. `.replace()` cannot be applied to arrays. `console.log(backdtring)` would have revealed that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/uj6rqjhf/

Comment: [`str.match(/\w+/g)`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ff6aupmL/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in the comments, you are trying to use a `String#replace` method on an array, see the description of the return value of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> An [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) if there were no matches.

To streamline tokenization, I'd rather use `.split(/(\([^()]*\))/)` to get all substrings in parentheses and the substrings that remain:

```js
var s = "hello(%npm%)hi";
var res = s.split(/(\([^()]*\))/);
console.log(res);
```

**Details**:

- `(\([^()]*\))` - the pattern is enclosed with capturing group so as `split` could return both the substrings that match and those that do not match the pattern
- `\(` -a literal `(`
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.